# If the result of creating is creation

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

then what is the result of getting?

Comment: I'm hoping its not receivership :)

Comment: gettiation ;) joking...

Comment: I thought the result of creating is a 'creature'

Comment: Which would make the result of getting a geture :-P

Comment: How about acquisition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be perfectly dry about it, the result of creating is either (a) there has been a(n act of) creation, or (b) there is now, in existence, a (new) creation. Describing the parallel conceptual relationships, the result of getting is either (a) a thing has been gotten, or (b) there is now, in my possession, a (new) thing. In the case of *getting*, these are concepts without single word signifiers. Sorry.

But I guess another way to answer your question is, "the result of *getting* is *thing*."

Answer (score 3):

The result of creating is creation. The result of destructing is destruction. So if the result of giving is gift, the result of getting must be gett :-P

But seriously, the result of getting can be "get". Perhaps not in U.S. English, but it is certainly quite common in British and New Zealand slang. It is quite common to hear something like "what was your get?" meaning "how much money did you make?", although it is much more common to hear "what was your catch?" in reference to things gotten.

I mentioned "gett" in humour, so in all seriousness, I proffer "obtainment".

Comment: "Destructing?" Mean you "destroying?" :)

Comment: Nope, I certainly mean "destructing", which is the present participle of "destruct", which means "to destroy something with intent". If I meant "destroy", I would have said "destroying". I certainly meant "destroy with intent", as "create" also implies intent (usually).

Answer (score 2):

I was always taught that "receive" is usually more preferable than "get," so I'd personally go with "reception."

Of course, we now have to decide what the act of getting reception is called. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Get" has a variety of meanings, for example "get drunk" means "become drunk" or "get upset" means "become upset". So in this case the result of a get is a "becoming". It can also mean "receive" as in "get a present" or "get a disease". The corresponding noun for "receive" is "receipt" but this noun also has other meanings. "Get" is also used in phrasal verbs, as in "get over it", "get on with it", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just "get." I know that word exists, at least. It usually refers to children, if memory serves me aright...or maybe it meant something like "ilk." I'm guessing that meaning is obsolete or it comes from "begetting", but that'd be my guess. :)